# Custom instruction in RISC-V that accesses non-operand registers? Also accessing memory?

Tags: riscv, gem5

I am trying to create a custom instruction in RISC-V using the instruction from this link https://nitish2112.github.io/post/adding-instruction-riscv/. However I haven't been able to figure out how to access registers that are not specified by the operands (that is not rd, rs1, rs2). I planned to create a "U" type instruction (such as lui or auipc) where the 20 bit immediate value would carry an immediate corresponding to the registers I desire to use (I plan to have each bit in the immediate indicate whether or not the register corresponding to that bit is an operand).

Also I was interested in accessing data that is not just a single 8byte. That is I wish to create an instruction where the register specified is the base of an array of n 8byte's. Alternatively I would be interested if there were a way to save multiple 8byte's onto the stack (using a single instruction).

I am trying to implement this in the gem5 simulator (in the arch/riscv/decoder.isa file). I know how to declare an instruction in the toolchain but I am having difficulty defining it in the simulator.